# Floating Action Button Missing

Tags: android, android-layout, floating-action-button

The code on floating action menu is working but other floating action buttons are not displayed. I have a Google Map and a recyclerview below the map. It seems that the map is covering the other floating action buttons. Below is the code for the floating action button. I followed a youtube video for it.

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout android:id="@+id/profilenav"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MapView"
    background="#FFF9C4"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

 <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:gravity="center">

            <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                tools:context=".MapviewPage"
                android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
                android:id="@+id/mapview"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="350dp"/>

            <view class="android.support.v7.app.AlertController$RecycleListView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:scrollbars="vertical"
                android:visibility="visible">
            </view>

        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>

        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/fab_margin_right"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:src="@drawable/menu"
            android:elevation="6dp"
            android:id="@+id/fab_nav"
            app:pressedTranslationZ="12dp"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/fab1_color"/>

        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/fab_margin_right"
            android:layout_marginBottom="100dp"
            android:src="@drawable/settings"
            android:elevation="6dp"
            android:id="@+id/fab_settings"
            app:pressedTranslationZ="12dp"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/fab2_color"
            android:visibility="invisible"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

The buttons should overlay on the Google Map and the recyclerview.

Comment: `android:visibility="invisible"` Could it be a reason ?

Comment: It should hide the other buttons until the user has not clicked on the floating menu button. It seems like it is only displaying 1 floating action button, and not the other 1.

Comment: Got it working already

Answer (score 1):

You have to add two more line in floating button.

```
  <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout android:id="@+id/profilenav"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
     background="#FFF9C4"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/test"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:gravity="center">


            <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                android:id="@+id/map"
                android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="350dp"
                tools:context=".view.activities.TestMap" />
            <view class="android.support.v7.app.AlertController$RecycleListView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:scrollbars="vertical"
                android:visibility="visible">

            </view>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/fab_margin_right"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_check_circle_black_24dp"
        android:elevation="6dp"
        android:id="@+id/fab_nav"
        app:pressedTranslationZ="12dp"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/color_type_help"/>
    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/fab_margin_right"
        android:layout_marginBottom="100dp"
        android:src="@drawable/logo"
        android:elevation="6dp"
        android:id="@+id/fab_settings"
        app:pressedTranslationZ="12dp"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/test"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/translucent"
        android:visibility="visible"/>
    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

three line add this in floating button.

```
    app:layout_anchor="@id/test"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
```